# Android: Use result from stringrequest in individual textviews

Tags: java, android

I have been able to get a string from an url, using volley. This string is now shown as one block in a textview. But I would like to be able to display this data in individual textviews. How could I do this?

Maybe important to know: I'm completely new at programming and this is my first week I'm doing this. So my method I used could be strange, and this might be a stupid question, but I'm just trying to learn, and to get the result I want.

This is the code I have now, to get the data from the url:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        textView.setText(response.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("error",error.toString());

    }
});

queue.add(request);
```

And this is how the result from the GET from the url looks like:

```
{"DeliveryDetailId":91003,"Delivery":{"DeliveryId":91,"DeliveryNumber":"1248","DropLocation":null,"DeliveryState":0},"ProductNumber":null,"Description":null,"PickLocation":"104","LocationCheck":null,"Quantity":64.0,"Histories":[],"BinNumberToUse":null}
```

So in this case I would like to have textviews which show the DeliveryID, Picklocation and Quantity. How can I extract this info from the string, so I can show it in the Textviews?

Comment: You request is not a StringRequest but a JsonObjectRequest. Research about it, create the POJOs corresponding your json object structure and retrieve each element you need by accessing the POJO, into your textviews

Comment: Ricardo, if I understand correctly, you mean I'm using the wrong method to fetch the data? I will look into Json. However, I have no idea what you mean with POJO :-)

Comment: POJO: Plain Old Java Object

Answer (score 0):

create model classes like below and store the response in Response.class
Then you can able to access  DeliveryID by calling getDeliveryID()

```
  -----------------------------------com.saranga.app.model.Delivery.java-----------------------------------


package com.saranga.app.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Delivery {

@SerializedName("DeliveryId")
@Expose
private Integer deliveryId;
@SerializedName("DeliveryNumber")
@Expose
private String deliveryNumber;
@SerializedName("DropLocation")
@Expose
private Object dropLocation;
@SerializedName("DeliveryState")
@Expose
private Integer deliveryState;

public Integer getDeliveryId() {
return deliveryId;
}

public void setDeliveryId(Integer deliveryId) {
this.deliveryId = deliveryId;
}

public String getDeliveryNumber() {
return deliveryNumber;
}

public void setDeliveryNumber(String deliveryNumber) {
this.deliveryNumber = deliveryNumber;
}

public Object getDropLocation() {
return dropLocation;
}

public void setDropLocation(Object dropLocation) {
this.dropLocation = dropLocation;
}

public Integer getDeliveryState() {
return deliveryState;
}

public void setDeliveryState(Integer deliveryState) {
this.deliveryState = deliveryState;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.saranga.app.model.Response.java-----------------------------------

package com.saranga.app.model;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

@SerializedName("DeliveryDetailId")
@Expose
private Integer deliveryDetailId;
@SerializedName("Delivery")
@Expose
private Delivery delivery;
@SerializedName("ProductNumber")
@Expose
private Object productNumber;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private Object description;
@SerializedName("PickLocation")
@Expose
private String pickLocation;
@SerializedName("LocationCheck")
@Expose
private Object locationCheck;
@SerializedName("Quantity")
@Expose
private Double quantity;
@SerializedName("Histories")
@Expose
private List<Object> histories = null;
@SerializedName("BinNumberToUse")
@Expose
private Object binNumberToUse;

public Integer getDeliveryDetailId() {
return deliveryDetailId;
}

public void setDeliveryDetailId(Integer deliveryDetailId) {
this.deliveryDetailId = deliveryDetailId;
}

public Delivery getDelivery() {
return delivery;
}

public void setDelivery(Delivery delivery) {
this.delivery = delivery;
}

public Object getProductNumber() {
return productNumber;
}

public void setProductNumber(Object productNumber) {
this.productNumber = productNumber;
}

public Object getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(Object description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getPickLocation() {
return pickLocation;
}

public void setPickLocation(String pickLocation) {
this.pickLocation = pickLocation;
}

public Object getLocationCheck() {
return locationCheck;
}

public void setLocationCheck(Object locationCheck) {
this.locationCheck = locationCheck;
}

public Double getQuantity() {
return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Double quantity) {
this.quantity = quantity;
}

public List<Object> getHistories() {
return histories;
}

public void setHistories(List<Object> histories) {
this.histories = histories;
}

public Object getBinNumberToUse() {
return binNumberToUse;
}

public void setBinNumberToUse(Object binNumberToUse) {
this.binNumberToUse = binNumberToUse;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your `JSONObject` and individually get each element unless it's in a `JSONArray` in that case you need to loop through it

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        textView.setText(json.getString("DeliveryDetailld"));
        JSONObject details = json.getJSONObject("Delivery");
        //Get data in Delivery Object
        textView2.setText(details.getString("DeliveryId"));
    }
```